# Rails way for generating DDL (or migration scripts) automatically from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema, ddl, rails-migrations

I started a new project and created ActiveRecord models simply by creating/editing the corresponding rb files. Now I would like to automatically generate the corresponding schema DDL so that the database can be created. Is there an automatic way to do this? Or do I need to manually write the migration script? The latter would be really pain in the neck. Also, it would be error-prone - which is why I am looking for some sort of automation.

Answer (score 0):

You generally create the migration scripts. There are scaffold generators built into rails that can generate the migration and model (and controller and views) at one time.

```
bin/rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer
```

This would create a migration for you with the appropriate fields:

```
class CreateHighScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :high_scores do |t|
      t.string :game
      t.integer :score

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

See the discussion under [generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) in the Rails documentation.